# How to debug Tensorflow on Windows

Tags: c++, c++11, tensorflow, visual-c++

What is the common way to debug Tensorflow on Windows (Tensorflow itself, C++ code)? MSVC has 4GB limit for .pdb file which makes it impossible to build debug version. 
Is there any way I can debug custom TF core code?

Answer (score 1):

From [VS 2019 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#debugger):

> For C++ applications running on Windows, PDB now load in a separate 64-bit process. This change addresses a range of crashes caused by the debugger running out of memory when debugging applications that contain a large number of modules and PDBs.

So I guess that 4Gb limit should not be an issue anymore.

Comment: WOW, that's nice! The only problem Google guys only officially support VS 2015, gonna be not that easy to compile with 2019, but anyway thank you so much!

Comment: @Dmitry I think it still supports old toolsets.

Comment: Ohhh I see. Nope, my issue is not how to load large PDB file but rather how to create the one. There is known issue with Microsoft linker, it does use 4KB page size for PDB files and as result can not create file more than 4GB in size.